# Tensorflow: Diagonal Subtensor for 3D Convolutional NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, tensorflow

Theano uses a workaround for a 3D convolutional neural (CNN) network using a variation on a 2D CNN:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/conv3d2d.py

It relies on being able to grab the diagonal of the matrix and reshape it. From the website above:

```
So the relevant part of `x` is some matrix `u`. Suppose it has 7 rows
and 4 columns::
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]

The view returned by this function is also a matrix. It is a thick,
diagonal `stripe` across u that discards the lower left triangle
and the upper right triangle:
    [ x 0 0 0 ]
    [ x x 0 0 ]
    [ x x x 0 ]
    [ 0 x x x ]
    [ 0 0 x x ]
    [ 0 0 0 x ]

In this case the return value would be this view of shape 3x4. The
returned view has the same number of dimensions as the input
`x`, and the only difference is that the shape along dimension
`i0` has been reduced by `shape[i1] - 1` because of the
triangles that got chopped out.
```

Can this be done in Tensorflow? This seems like a relatively easy task that can still use the vast majority of Tensorflow's CNN framework while handling 3D datatypes.

Comment: Here's an example of extracting two diagonals from a matrix, you could generalize it to extract n diagonals and stack them together: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34910627/419116

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - could you put that comment into an answer so the question is 'answered'?  Thanks!