# Interpolated sampling of points in an image with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given is a grayscale image **I** as 2D Tensor (Dimension W,H) and a Tensor of coordinates **C** (Dim. None,2). I want to interpret the rows of **C** as coordinates in **I**, sample **I** at those coordinates using some kind of interpolation (bilinear would probably be fine for my use case), and store the resulting values in a new Tensor **P** (of dimension None, i.e. 1-dimensional with as many entries as **C** has rows).

Is this possible (efficiently) with TensorFlow? All I can find are functions for resizing (equidistant resampling if you like) of images. But I can't find anything out-of-the-box to sample at a list of coordinates.

I.e. I would have expected to find something like a tf.interpolate() function:

```
I = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[128, 128])
C = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 2])
P = tf.interpolate(I, C, axis=[0, 1], method="linear")
```

Ideally I would be looking for a solution that would allow me to interpolate in an N dimensional tensor **I** along M dimensions using a **C** with shape (None, M) and produce an N-M+1 dimensional output, as indicated by the "axis" parameter in the code above.

(The "image" in my application isn't a picture btw., it's sampled data from a physical model (when used as placeholder) or an alternative learned model (when used as variable). Right now this physical model has 2 degrees of freedom, thus interpolating in an "image" is sufficient for now, but I might look into higher dimensional models in the future.)

In case something like that is not possible with existing TensorFlow features: Where should I start when I'd like to implement something like this tf.interpolate() operator? (documentation and/or simple example code)

Comment: There's efficient way to do nearest neighbor interpolation using tf.gather...not sure about linear interpolation

Comment: There is `tf.image.resize_bilinear`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Albert No. This would only do what I want if I wanted to sample the source images on all points on a grid. But the rows of C can be any coordinates in the source image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in op that performs this kind of interpolation, but you should be able to do it using a composition of existing TensorFlow ops. I'd suggest the following strategy for the bilinear case:

1. From your tensor `C` of indices, compute integer tensors corresponding to the four corner points. For example (with names assuming that the origin is at the top left):

   ```
   top_left = tf.cast(tf.floor(C), tf.int32)

   top_right = tf.cast(
       tf.concat(1, [tf.floor(C[:, 0:1]), tf.ceil(C[:, 1:2])]), tf.int32)

   bottom_left = tf.cast(
       tf.concat(1, [tf.ceil(C[:, 0:1]), tf.floor(C[:, 1:2])]), tf.int32)

   bottom_right = tf.cast(tf.ceil(C), tf.int32)
   ```
2. From each tensor representing a particular corner point, extract a vector of values from `I` at those points. For example, for the following function does this for the 2-D case:

   ```
   def get_values_at_coordinates(input, coordinates):
     input_as_vector = tf.reshape(input, [-1])
     coordinates_as_indices = (coordinates[:, 0] * tf.shape(input)[1]) + coordinates[:, 1]
     return tf.gather(input_as_vector, coordinates_as_indices)

   values_at_top_left = get_values_at_coordinates(I, top_left)
   values_at_top_right = get_values_at_coordinates(I, top_right)
   values_at_bottom_left = get_values_at_coordinates(I, bottom_left)
   values_at_bottom_right = get_values_at_coordinates(I, bottom_right)
   ```
3. Compute the interpolation in the horizontal direction first:

   ```
   # Varies between 0.0 and 1.0.
   horizontal_offset = C[:, 0] - tf.cast(top_left[:, 0], tf.float32)

   horizontal_interpolated_top = (
       ((1.0 - horizontal_offset) * values_at_top_left)
       + (horizontal_offset * values_at_top_right))

   horizontal_interpolated_bottom = (
       ((1.0 - horizontal_offset) * values_at_bottom_left)
       + (horizontal_offset * values_at_bottom_right))
   ```
4. Now compute the interpolation in the vertical direction:

   ```
   vertical_offset = C[:, 1] - tf.cast(top_left[:, 1], tf.float32)

   interpolated_result = (
       ((1.0 - vertical_offset) * horizontal_interpolated_top)
       + (vertical_offset * horizontal_interpolated_bottom))
   ```

Comment: Can this applied to batched rgb images? I tried just changing `get_values_at_coordinates()` to reshape the image to `input_as_vector = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 3])` (C = 3) but it's not working!

Comment: The code in the answer is specialized for a single grayscale image (as in the question), but you might be able to apply it to a batch of images by using `tf.map_fn()` to apply it across a batch.

Comment: Would anything change for RGB images, that is before applying `tf.map_fn()`? Still failing to make it work.

Comment: If it's possible to interpolate each channel independently, you could do something like `images_red, images_green, images_blue = tf.unstack(images, axis=3)` to get the separate channels, then use `tf.map_fn()` to interpolate each channel, and `tf.stack([interpolated_red, interpolated_green, interpolated_blue])` to recombine the image. If that doesn't work, feel free to ask a new question with exactly what code you've tried and the error you're seeing!

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be tricky for nearest neighbor given that TF doesn't have Numpy slicing generality yet ([github issue #206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206)), and the fact that `gather` only works on first dimension. But here's a way to work around it by using gather->transpose->gather->extract diagonal

```
def identity_matrix(n):
  """Returns nxn identity matrix."""
  # note, if n is a constant node, this assert node won't be executed,
  # this error will be caught during shape analysis 
  assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.greater(n, 0), ["Matrix size must be positive"])
  with tf.control_dependencies([assert_op]):
    ones = tf.fill(n, 1)
    diag = tf.diag(ones)
  return diag

def extract_diagonal(tensor):
  """Extract diagonal of a square matrix."""

  shape = tf.shape(tensor)
  n = shape[0]
  assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.equal(shape[0], shape[1]), ["Can't get diagonal of "
                                                       "a non-square matrix"])

  with tf.control_dependencies([assert_op]):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(tensor, identity_matrix(n)), [0])


# create sample matrix
size=4
I0=np.zeros((size,size), dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(size):
  for j in range(size):
    I0[i, j] = 10*i+j

I = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.int32, shape=(size,size))
C = tf.placeholder(np.int32, shape=[None, 2])
C0 = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]])
row_indices = C[:, 0]
col_indices = C[:, 1]

# since gather only supports dim0, have to transpose
I1 = tf.gather(I, row_indices)
I2 = tf.gather(tf.transpose(I1), col_indices)
I3 = extract_diagonal(tf.transpose(I2))

sess = create_session()
print sess.run([I3], feed_dict={I:I0, C:C0})
```

So starting with a matrix like this:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [30, 31, 32, 33]], dtype=int32)
```

This code extracts diagonal one above the main

```
[array([ 1, 12, 23], dtype=int32)]
```

There's some magic happening with [] operators getting turned into `Squeeze` and `Slice`

[image]