# Image warping in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, torch

I'm working with video sequences and optical flows. I'd like to know, whether Tensorflow has operation for warping images. Analog to image.warp in Torch https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/paramtransform.md

If there is no such operation build in, maybe there is open source code for that. Or you could provide pointers for me to implement this operation in TF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a built in function yet. But the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910583) might help you.

Its built with standard Tensorflow Ops and doing a [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation), but I guess it won't be very fast in comparison to a truly CUDA optimized Op. Also you need to expand it for batches, color images and the kind of padding you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In `tf2` it is moved to `TensorFlow Addons` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/dense_image_warp)):

```
@tf.function
tfa.image.dense_image_warp(
    image: tfa.types.TensorLike,
    flow: tfa.types.TensorLike,
    name: Optional[str] = None
) -> tf.Tensor
```

Answer (score -2):

Opencv have these functions: `warpPerspective()`, `perspectiveTransform()`